# R Plotly Time Series data displaying at date instead of datetime

Tags: r, time-series, powerbi, plotly

I am trying to plot time series data using a plotly range slider graph in Power BI. I'm running into issues whereby the values are being plot on a date basis rather than on datetime basis. Almost as if the time portion is being lost

Here is a sample of my raw data

```
Datetime           Legend          Value
24/01/2019 6:30    A1 RT8EACBT      34
24/01/2019 6:41    A1 RT1EASIVT     46
24/01/2019 6:41    A1 RT8EACBT      33
24/01/2019 6:50    A1 RT1EASIVT     45
24/01/2019 6:50    A1 RT8EACBT      33
24/01/2019 7:00    A1 RT1EASIVT     45
24/01/2019 7:00    A1 RT8EACBT      33
24/01/2019 7:11    A1 RT1EASIVT     43
24/01/2019 7:11    A1 RT8EACBT      33
24/01/2019 7:20    A1 RT1EASIVT     45
24/01/2019 7:20    A1 RT8EACBT      35
24/01/2019 7:31    A1 RT1EASIVT     45
24/01/2019 7:31    A1 RT8EACBT      34
```

Below is the plotly output

[Plotly Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VydTs.png)

Below is the code I am using

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

# My data frame is called Values

p <- plot_ly(Values, x = ~as.POSIXct(Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s"), y = ~Value, color= ~Legend, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%

  layout(
    title = "Test",
    xaxis = list(
      rangeselector = list(
        buttons = list(
          list(
            count = 3,
            label = "3 mo",
            step = "month",
            stepmode = "backward"),
          list(
            count = 6,
            label = "6 mo",
            step = "month",
            stepmode = "backward"),
          list(
            count = 1,
            label = "1 yr",
            step = "year",
            stepmode = "backward"),
          list(
            count = 1,
            label = "YTD",
            step = "year",
            stepmode = "todate"),
          list(step = "all"))),

      rangeslider = list(type = "date")),

    yaxis = list(title = "Values"))
```

https://plot.ly/r/time-series/

Comment: If your data looks like the sample you provided the issue is your format specification in `as.POSIXct()`. For your Datetime column it should be `as.POSIXct(Datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't have the format correct. I tried your formatting (I had to remove the `format =` bit to get the x axis to render as a datetime)and I also tried  `as.POSIXct(Datetime, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S")` however it still displays all values against midnight (00:00:00)

Comment: Could you please add the output of `str(Values)`?